# Makefile: removing files

Tags: makefile

On Windows I am trying to add a `Makefile` target to remove all files from a specific directory (NOT including subdirectories)...

```
clean_files:
    rm -f Build/*.*
```

But I get the error: `/bin/sh: rm: command not found`

Running it from the command line works and running it without the `*`'s works.

Comment: Assuming *nix environment, what do you get from `which rm`?

Comment: You can't use `rm` (or, from below, `find`) in a Windows environment.  Those are POSIX commands, and Windows is not POSIX.  You'll have to either install a POSIX environment on your system (such as cygwin), which is a major change, or use Windows commands such as `del` instead of `rm`.

Answer (score 3):

```
clean_files:
    - rm -f Build/*
```

putting a '-' before a make command will ignore any errors from that command, like

```
rm: cannot remove `Build/subdir': Is a directory
```

Comment: just to add to this, it won't completely ignore the errors, it will just proceed as-is if there is any errors, errors will still be output to the screen

Answer (score 1):

For removing all files from directory (NOT including sub-directories) consider:

```
clean_files:
    find Build/ -type f -maxdepth 1 -delete
```